# Search LIKE? only if it meets a certan requirement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Please excuse any of my terminology if its off. In my model I am trying to define a method that would search 2 columns unless another column(boolean) is true.

```
class BusinessStore < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :business_name, :address, :online_store, :website

  def store
    "#{business_name} - #{address}" 
  end
end
```

`:business_name` is a virtual attribute, `:online_store` is a boolean column.

I want to take the `:online_store` and make a method like this:

```
def store
 "#{business_name} - #{address}" unless business_store.online_store = true
end
```

So it shouldn't show Business Stores that are flagged as true for being online stores because I am looking for Retail stores only; stores with addresses. Here is my model controller. Just to clarify again, `BusinessStore.where` should omit searching stores with `online_store = true`

```
class BusinessStoresController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @business_stores = BusinessStore.all
    @business_stores = BusinessStore.where("address like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @business_stores }
      format.json { render :json => @business_stores.collect{|b|{:id => b.id, :name => b.store } } }
    end
  end
end
```

This isn't working becuase my business_stores.json gets a NameError:

```
http://localhost:3000/business_stores.json
NameError in BusinessStoresController#index

undefined local variable or method `business_store' for...
```

How do you define this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're kind of asking for two different things I think. If you want to fetch all physical stores where `online_store != true`, you could just define a scope for it.

```
class BusinessStore < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :business_name, :address, :online_store, :website
  scope :stores, where(:online_store => false)
  # or alternately
  scope :alternate_stores, where("online_store IS NOT NULL")
  # depending on default values
end
```

That doesn't exclude it from the where() method however. You COULD overload that method, but I don't think this situation calls for that.

```
def store
  "#{business_name} - #{address}" unless business_store.online_store = true
end
```

The above code works just fine, if that's what you want (see what I mean about asking for two things?). You just need to change it to

```
"#{business_name} - #{address}" unless self.online_store == true
```

The error your seeing is because you don't have an object named business_store, you should access the variable on the object itself instead. And you need double =, otherwise you're actually setting the variable to true, which in Ruby will be true in the eyes of the if/unless as well.

Comment: Adding proper hooks, validations, and CHECK constraints so that `address is null` if and only if `not online` would also help, then `where('address like ?', ...)` would never match an online store because NULL isn't LIKE anything.